# How to insert records in table for every month

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic, plsql

I've created table for each month like **TBL_ABC_JAN**, **TBL_ABC_FEB**, .... **TBL_ABC_DEC**. I've created 1 Stored Procedure to insert records into the tables for every months. So I used Dynamic SQL to insert the record but don't know how to insert the record into the table that mentioned above for every month. Could you please help me to let me know the logic behind these insertion. The insertion will be done automatically, because it's a Stored Procedure.

Comment: insert  select  ... what's your real issue ..   try add  a data sample and the expected  result

Comment: This approach is most probably **wrong**. There should be one table with a DATE column. Even if you fix the current problem ("how to insert ..."), you'll hit another when you'll have to select rows from some of those tables. Will you write 12 queries which look **exactly** the same, with only difference in source table name? Whatever you do, whenever you do that, you'll have problems because of wrong data model. I'd suggest you to reconsider it and - eventually - abandon it.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks for give me the suggestion. DATE column has been mentioned in the table. So for every month I've to write 12 `insert` statement for every month or anything else so that I can apply.

Comment: The correct solution is to have one common table, instead of one table per month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need such a design then you can use `INSERT FIRST`.

```
INSERT FIRST
  WHEN to_char(DATE_COL,'MON') = 'JAN' THEN
    INTO TBL_ABC_JAN VALUES(....)
WHEN to_char(DATE_COL,'MON') = 'FEB' THEN
    INTO TBL_ABC_FEB VALUES(....)
..
..
..
WHEN to_char(DATE_COL,'MON') = 'NOV' THEN
INTO TBL_ABC_NOV VALUES(....)
ELSE
INTO TBL_ABC_DEC VALUES(....) 
SELECT DATE_COL, ......
FROM   source_table;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider only creating one table with a month-column in it.